# How to deal with transient entities after deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, objectmapper, modelmapper

Let's say I have a simple REST app with Controller, Service and Data layers. In my Controller layer I do something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/items")
void save(ItemDTO dto){

    Item item = map(dto, Item.class);
    service.validate(item);
    service.save(item);
}
```

But then I get errors because my Service layer looks like this:

```
public void validate(Item item) {
    
     if(item.getCategory().getCode().equals(5)){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Items with category 5 are not currently permitted");
     }

}
```

I get a NullPointerException at `.equals(5)`, because the `Item` entity was deserialized from a DTO that only contains `category_id`, and nothing else (all is `null` except for the `id`).

The solutions we have found and have experimented with, are:

1. Make a special deserializer that takes the `id`s and automatically fetches the required entities. This, of course, resulted in massive performance problems, similar to those you would get if you marked all your relationships with `FetchType.EAGER`.
2. Make the Controller layer fetch all the entities the Service layer will need. The problem is, the Controller needs to know how the underlying service works exactly, and what it will need.
3. Have the Service layer verify if the object needs fetching before running any validations. The problem is, we couldn't find a reliable way of determining whether an object needs fetching or not. We end up with ugly code like this **everywhere**:

(sample)

```
if(item.getCategory().getCode() == null)
    item.setCategory(categoryRepo.findById(item.getCategory().getId()));
```

What other ways would you do it to keep Services easy to work with? It's really counterintuitive for us having to check every time we want to use a related entity.

Please note this question is not about finding any way to solve this problem. It's more about finding better ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, it would be very difficult for modelMapper to map an id that is in the DTO to the actual entity.
The problem is that modelMapper or some service would have to do a lookup and inject the entity.

1. If the category is a finite set, could use an ENUM and use static ENUM mapping?
2. Could switch the logic to read
   `if(listOfCategoriesToAvoid.contains(item.getCategory())){ throw new IllegalArgumentException("Items with category 5 are not currently permitted"); }`
   and you could populate the listOfCategoriesToAvoid small query, maybe even store it in a properties file/table where it could be a CSV?
3. When you call the service.save(item), wouldn't it still fail to populate the category because that wouldn't be populated? Maybe you can send the category as a CategoryDTO inside the itemDTO that populated the Category entity on the model.map() call.

Not sure if any of these would work for you.

Comment: Sadly, those are not finite sets. About #3, we used to do that in the past, but it made consuming the API a nightmare.

The validation I added makes it seem like Category is a finite set, but it's not. That specific example doesn't exist in our real application. I guess I should have looked for a better one.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather the `map(dto, Item.class)` method does something like this:

```
Long categoryId = itemDto.getCategoryId();
Category cat = new Category();
cat.setId(categoryId);
outItem.setCategory(cat);
```

The simplest solution would be to have it do this inside:

```
Long categoryId = itemDto.getCategoryId();
Category cat = categoryRepo.getById(categoryId);
outItem.setCategory(cat);
```

Another option is since you are hardcoding the category code 5 until its finished, you could hard-code the category IDs that have it instead, if those are not something that you expect to be changed by users.

Comment: Thanks, but exactly this is the first solution in the list I provided above. It caused massive performance problems for us.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just using the `code` as primary key for `Category`? This way you don't have to fetch anything for this kind of check. The underlying problem though is that the object mapper is just not able to cope with the managed nature of JPA objects i.e. it doesn't know that it should actually retrieve objects by PK through e.g. `EntityManager#getReference`. If it were doing that, then you wouldn't have a problem as the proxy returned by that method would be lazily initialized on the first call to `getCode`.

I suggest you look at something like [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which has first class support for something like that.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Item.class)
// You can omit the strategy to default to QUERY when using the code as PK of Category
@UpdatableEntityView(strategy = FlushStrategy.ENTITY)
public interface ItemDTO {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
    CategoryDTO getCategory();
    void setCategory(CategoryDTO category);

    @EntityView(Category.class)
    interface CategoryDTO {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ItemDTO a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ItemDTO.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ItemDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

And in your case of saving data, you can use the [Spring WebMvc integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#entity-view-deserialization)
that would look something like the following:

```
@PostMapping("/items")
void save(ItemDTO dto){
    service.save(dto);
}

class ItemService {
  @Autowired
  ItemRepository repository;
  
  @Transactional
  public void save(ItemDTO dto) {
    repository.save(dto);
    Item item = repository.getOne(dto);
    validate(item);
  }

  // other code...
}
```